# jquery ajax call returning Html page insteed of json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

i am making ajax calling system for call subcategories but it in response it giving in html format instead of json format my ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#cat_id').on('change',function(e) {

         var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();
            console.log(cat_id)
         $.ajax({

               url:"/admin/category/child",
               type:"POST",
               accept: 'application/json',
               data: {
                   cat_id: cat_id
                },

               success:function (response) {
                alert('ok');
                console.log(response)

                $('#child_cat_id').empty();
                if(typeof(response) !='object'){
                    response=JSON.parse(response)
                }
                console.log(typeof(response));
                $.each(response.data,function(id,title){

                    $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+id+'">'+title+'</option>');
                })

               },
               error:function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
           })
        });

    });
</script>
```

In Route i use following for create link to get response:

```
    // Ajax for sub category
    Route::post('admin/category/child','CategoryController@getChildByParent');
```

in CategoryController@getChildByParent i add following code to pass sub categories to the page with json response:

```
    public function getChildByParent(Request $request){
        $category=Category::findOrFail($request->cat_id);
        $child_cat=Category::getChildByParentID($request->cat_id);
        if(count($child_cat)<=0){
            return response()->json(['status'=>false,'msg'=>'','data'=>null]);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>true,'msg'=>'','data'=>$child_cat]);
        }
    }
```

in console i got html page :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does you Ajax call throwing an exception?

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand

Comment: check the place from where you are getting response, eg. controller & check the return data type.

Comment: i tried returning requst and also dd but give same response if i try to put datatype: 'json', it thorw error

Comment: That seems like a middleware or exception issue, do you have any middleware defined for that function? Or did you include the CSRF token? If the response status code is 419, that might be the issue.

Comment: yes middleware were included

Comment: thank you after removing middleware it worked :)